# Advantages of "typed Racket" over Racket

Tags: scheme, racket, typed

What are the main advantages one can expect from using "#lang typed/racket" over "#lang racket"? I could not find it in the references https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/index.html . Are the advantages just as for any other statically typed programming language https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#STATIC ? Is it reasonable to expect improvement in speed of compiled programs? Is safety of programs also improved? Thanks for your insight.

Comment: Many of the numerical libraries claim to be significantly faster with `typed racket`. In general, my experience writing code is that `typed racket` has similar tradeoffs that one finds when comparing statically typed languages to dynamically typed languages -- with the caveat that both the dynamically typed and statically typed versions of `racket` are strongly typed. Static typing adds friction to several lisp idioms, sometimes it's worth it, sometimes it is not.

Comment: Seems a reasonably good answer to me. You should post this as an answer and not just a comment. Also, is safety also affected?

Comment: Thanks. Honestly, I'm not really a fan of the question. Not that I flagged it, but it seems mostly opinion based and my answer is likewise not all that useful...I mean there's not much more to say about `typed racket` than it's statically typed and reasonably well implemented. Anyone looking to use the numeric libraries will see the claim that they run faster with Typed Racket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [Typed Racket Guide](https://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/optimization.html)

> ### 7 Optimization in Typed Racket
>
> Typed Racket provides a type-driven optimizer that rewrites well-typed
> programs to potentially make them faster. It should in no way make
> your programs slower or unsafe.

Thus the type hinting can make your programs faster, but it guarantees the programs wont be slower than `#lang racket` as well.

Note that this is true when you compile it with `raco make` or use DrRacket to make an executable. Running the code in the IDE might be slower because of the extra work the compiler does to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Some of the libraries claim to be much fasted in Typed Racket.

From the Racket documentation:

## 7 Matrices and Linear Algebra

Performance Warning: Matrix values are arrays, as exported by math/array. 
 The same performance warning applies: operations are currently 25-50 times 
 slower in untyped Racket than in Typed Racket, due to the overhead of 
 checking higher-order contracts. We are working on it.

https://docs.racket-lang.org/math/matrices.html?q=matrix